# Running python 3.7 on miniconda on raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3b+, python-3

I want to use python 3.7 in raspberry pi through miniconda but surfing, I got to know that miniconda provides python version upto 3.4. Some sources said to use berryconda, which I installed but still the `conda info` states my python version is 3.6. I tried to install python 3.7 through `conda install python=3.7`. But as u might have guessed that didnt work as well. I do have python 3.7 manually installed but I don't think there is a way to make conda use that version (please correct me if I'm wrong and tell me how).

I want to create an environment with these dependencies, but it seems I'm stuck on the first step (python 3.7):

name: yolov4-cpu

dependencies:

- python==3.7
- pip
- matplotlib
- opencv
- pip:

  - opencv-python==4.1.1.26
  - lxml
  - tqdm
  - tensorflow==2.3.0rc0
  - absl-py
  - easydict
  - pillow

Is there a solution for my problem?

Answer (score -1):

How about try

```
conda create -n env_name python=3.7
conda activate env_name
```

or

```
source activate env_name
```

Comment: that dosn't work..i did try that already